# Get Image Size before Image is Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-masonry, image-size

I am using JQuery Masonry and hoping to implement Lazy Load via the wordpress plugin to load images when they appear in the viewport.

The problem is that when using lazy load the masonry elements do not know the image size when outside the viewport and therefore are not spacing the masonry elements correctly.

Without the Lazy Load plugin activated the masonry code works fine.

Is there any way of obtaining the image dimensions via jQuery prior to the image being loaded and set these dimensions in the placeholder for the image -> this basically means setting the height and width to the image placeholder element at the time the masonry container is created.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way. But you do have options which include using some server-side coding (here is a [php example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)) to provide the dimensions (using something like ajax), or use an image loaded callback script to update masonry - try the [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin written by the same author.

Comment: I have implemented the `imagesloaded` plugin already. I will look at the server side code. :) Thankyou